# Update tableView's headerView on device rotation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have table view with a custom header view. In the header view I have a subview that is a UIImage. On rotation, the header view and it's subviews don't update to where they should be. Instead, they retain their positions until the user either presses a button, moves to a different page, etc. Essentially, their positions don't update until the user interacts with the app in some way.

I am detecting device rotation with:

```
    override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        // Update header views!
    }
```

I can't find any sort of code that will update the header view and it's subviews though. Any help appreciated.

EDIT: Here is the code for my header view:

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.sectionHeaderHeight))
        let headerColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        headerView.backgroundColor = headerColor

        headerView.tag = section

        let headerString = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: tableView.frame.size.width-45, height: 30)) as UILabel
        headerString.text = "Title"
        headerString.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        headerView.addSubview(headerString)
        let headerTapped = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:"sectionHeaderTapped:")
        headerView.addGestureRecognizer(headerTapped)

        // Button in header
        let gearImage = UIImage(named: "icons_button")
        let width = CGFloat(45)
        let rightInset = CGFloat(10)
        let headerButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: headerView.frame.maxX - 45, y: 7, width: width, height: width - rightInset))
        headerButton.setImage(gearImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        headerButton.tag = section
        headerButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: rightInset)
        headerButton.addTarget(self, action: "userButtonPress:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        headerView.addSubview(headerButton)

        return headerView
    }
```

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: Yes i am using storyboards

Comment: Have you considered using Autolayout? You can set constraints in the storyboard or in code

Answer (score 2):

in viewForHeaderInSection add a container like UIVIEW
and then in container add childview like label then 
add this line

```
label.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it seems like overkill, this works well:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
  [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition: ^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> _Nonnull context) {
    [_myTableView reloadData];
  } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {
    [_myTableView reloadData];
  }];
}
```

Comment: This helped me. But why are there two reloads? I ended up with `reloadData` during the animate closure and kept the completion handler free.

Comment: I guess it depends on your header view code, but sometimes the animation steps didn't include the final positions, so the completion reload made it all good once it was finished.

Answer (score 0):

in your rotation func:

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: This doesn't fix my problem. I tried using layoutIfNeeded() on different views but still no change.

Comment: How is your header frame set? Auto layout or programmatically?

Comment: Header frame and it's subviews are set programmatically with CGRect

Comment: And I assume you recall the function to set these in your `viewWillTransitionToSize`? Or create a new frame, something like `header.frame = CGRect(x: pageCenter, y: 0, width: pageWidth, height: 50)`?

Comment: I guess I need to reload the header view? I can't figure out what to call in `viewWillTransitionToSize` to reload the header in my table view

Comment: Show your original code that creates the header view.

Comment: Added my `viewForHeaderInSection` to the original post